# Is there a way to tell if a given string is a sha256 hash?

Tags: sha-256

Just like, for instance, we can easily check if a given number is a visa card number, by verifying prefix and checksum - can we do anything similar for hash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hashes have no defined structure as e.g. IBAN bank account numbers, to follow your example (not sure about the case for credit cards).

The output of SHA is essentially a number value, without checksums or other additional elements.

To answer your question, the only check you can perform is to verify that the potential SHA-256 hash is 256-bits long. In fact, since you can feed arbitrary inputs into the algorithm, any 256-bit value will be a correct SHA-256 hash for some input(s).

---

Since you mention strings as the datatype to check: note that the “string” hash is commonly a minimal hexadecimal representation of said hash. The minimal form of hexadecimals consists of two digits per byte, where each digit is a character ranging from `0` to `9`, `a` to `f` or `A` to `F`.

So if your candidate string contains any other letters/symbols it can be rejected. This is a trivial check that lets you distinguish between (2 * 32 = 64) hexadecimals and other text - it doesn't proof that the bytes are the output of a hash function.

Comment: Technically we can't prove that SHA-256 is surjective, though it likely is (and it doesn't really matter in practice).

Comment: The output of the SHA families of hashes is defined as **bits**, usually grouped together as **bytes**, as bitarrays are usually not present or effective on runtimes of computers. So "The output of SHA is essentially a **number** value" is **not** technically correct.